# Scroll view white space in the bottom ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, whitespace

Hello i am working on the scrollview followed many tutorials found on stack overflow and youtube but facing same problem in the all tutorials , i want that if there is no content in the bottom there should be no white space whatever the view size is, in this pic you can see there is no content in the bottom many so much white space there are two labels in this image one is on footer and second is in the center i want that if there is nothing after the center there should be no more scrollview  how to rid of this please guide me

[image: white space scrolview]

this is my storyboard

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, The problem is that if you want to the scrollview to be just the size of the content you have then you need to have to set

```
scrollView.ContentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
```

If the problem is not solved with this then you have to check your constraint that must be incorrect.

Also to get the correct height you must have **added bottom constraint to last element i.e footer** i.e footer.bottom = safeArea.bottom (in storyboard inspector)

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: just adjust the bottom constraint of the last element in the content view of your scroll view